# shell script : array related issue

Tags: bash, shell, snmp

using linux 2.6.18..

```
/bin/bash -version
GNU bash, version 1.14.7(1)
```

(snmpwalk command gives output in a console like...below)

```
33
4232
5342
632
45342
23342
3243
```

I am using shell script to grep data from snmp and trying to add it in array. but cannot do this with following problems...

```
#!/bin/bash
OID="1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1"

declare -a index=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.1) 
declare -a upload=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.10) 
declare -a download=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.11)

echo "retrieved ${#index[@]} elements"
echo "#${index[3]}: up=${upload[2]} down=${download[2]}"
```

output:

```
 + declare -a index=1 2
    j2.sh: 4: j2.sh: declare: not found
```

(so I can not use 'declare')

2nd way

```
#!/bin/bash

    OUTPUT1=$(snmpbulkwalk -Oqv -c public -v 2c localhost
    1.3.6.1.4.1.21067.4.1.1.1 2> /dev/null)
    i=1
    index=1
    upload=1
    download=1
    for LINE in ${OUTPUT1}
        do
            index=$LINE

        OUTPUT2=$(snmpget -Oqv -c public -v 2c localhost 1.3.6.1.4.1.21067.4.1.1.10.$i 2> /dev/null)
        OUTPUT3=$(snmpget -Oqv -c public -v 2c localhost 1.3.6.1.4.1.21067.4.1.1.11.$i 2> /dev/null)
            upload=$OUTPUT2
            download=$OUTPUT3
            i=`expr $i + 1`
        done
```

its gives bettelnack with large amount of data...

3ra approch :

```
#!/bin/bash
OUTPUT=$(snmpbulkwalk -Oqv -c public -v 2c localhost
1.3.6.1.4.1.21067.4.1.1.1 2> /dev/null)
i=0
index[3000]=0
for LINE in ${OUTPUT} ; do
    index[$i]=$LINE
    i=`expr $i + 1`

done
```

here index[1],index[2]...... are not fount

Answer (score 1):

```
declare -a index=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.1) declare -a upload=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.10) declare -a download=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.11)
```

Why are you trying to do this all on one line? Do this on separate lines and it should work.

```
declare -a index=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.1)
declare -a upload=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.10)
declare -a download=$(snmpwalk -v 2c -c public -Oqv localhost ${OID}.11)
```

If that doesn't work, what version of Bash are you using? What do you get from `/bin/bash --version`?

Comment: Two other options: separate the commands with semi-colon, or declare all three variables in the same command: `declare -a index=$(...) upload=$(...) download=$(...)`

Comment: I have done in separate line. Its just paste mistake over here.. sorry..  But my bash is not supporting "declare" or any kind of normal array declaration.... can you help me with that ?

Comment: /bin/bash -version GNU bash, version 1.14.7(1)   {I can not upgrade bash version in my server}

Comment: @user95711 Seriously? Bash 1.14? I can't find release notes going all the way back to Bash 2, which is when `declare -a` support was added, but Bash 2.05 was [released in 2001](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2001-04/msg00005.html). You're using a version of Bash that is more than 11 years old. Anyhow, the version of Bash you are using is too old to have support for arrays. What are you actually trying to do? If you describe what problem you are trying to solve, I can probably describe how you can do it without using arrays.

Comment: Actually in organization with whom I am working has its oven linux vcersion since past 11 years. with this script  I am fatching some data form " net-snmp" module and than  with this answers I wand to update different "RRD" graphes.   so the values and the graphs are too large, and "SNMPGET (greping all the data one by one )" gives me bottleneck. so with "SNMPWALK" I am fatching all the data at once and store it someware... so after it I can get them according to my need